# An item with the same key has already been added. When Deserialize an object in c#

Tags: c#

I am deserializing an object and i get the titled error. Code bellow

```
byte[] dataBuffer = TransmissionBuffer.ToArray();
dataBuffer = Decompress(dataBuffer);
BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
mem.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
mem.Seek(0, 0);

return (SendWorldData)bin.Deserialize(mem);
```

Error is on the return line.

Here is the clipboarded exception

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.OnDeserialization(Object sender)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DeserializationEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RaiseDeserializationEvent()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
       at TheDarkAgesReturn.SendWorldData.DeSerialize() in C:\SVNProjects\Dark Ages Return\TheDarkAgesReturn2008NET3.5V1.5\TheDarkAgesReturn\SendWorldData.cs:line 64
       at TheDarkAgesReturn.ClientDarkAges.Done(SendWorldData status) in C:\SVNProjects\Dark Ages Return\TheDarkAgesReturn2008NET3.5V1.5\TheDarkAgesReturn\ClientDarkAges.cs:line 125
       at TheDarkAgesReturn.ClientDarkAges.Receive(IAsyncResult result) in C:\SVNProjects\Dark Ages Return\TheDarkAgesReturn2008NET3.5V1.5\TheDarkAgesReturn\ClientDarkAges.cs:line 108
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
       at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
  InnerException:
```

The class structure is below;

```
public LinkedList<Person> allPeople = new LinkedList<Person>();
public LinkedList<Person> allDeadPeople = new LinkedList<Person>();
public LinkedList<Plant> allTrees = new LinkedList<Plant>();
public List<Building> allBuildings = new List<Building>();
public List<LargeTool> allLargeTools = new List<LargeTool>();
public List<CollectedRawMaterial> allCollectedItems = new List<CollectedRawMaterial>();
public List<Boar> allBoar = new List<Boar>();
public LinkedList<Animal> allAntelope = new LinkedList<Animal>();
public LinkedList<Animal> allChickens = new LinkedList<Animal>();
public List<Deposit> allOre = new List<Deposit>();
public List<History> allHistory = new List<History>();
public Boolean Completed = true;

[NonSerialized]
public Socket Socket;
[NonSerialized]
public List<byte> TransmissionBuffer = new List<byte>();
[NonSerialized]
public byte[] buffer = new byte[5500000];
```

If you need more information i can provide this. I expect it is something simple but i just cant work it out. Of course this could be something to do with a duplicate key in a dictionary if so how to drill down further to find this out.

Thanks for all help in advance.

Scott

Answer (score 2):

Are you using sets somewhere? Both the `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>` and the `Iesi.Collection.Generic` set classes (those shipped with the O/R mapper NHibernate) are troublesome. I switched to an `IList<T>` to work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try temporarily serializing and de-serializing the individual members instead of the whole class to narrow down which member contains the dictionary with the duplicate key so you can focus your attention on a smaller area.

Comment: Interesting idea, just exactly how would you do that?

Comment: In addition there are no dictionaries de-serializing so how can this be?

Comment: @Scott 1) When you serialize the object, instead of serializing yourSendWorldDataInstance, serialize yourSendWorldDataInstance.allPeople. When you deserialize, cast the result to LinkedList<Person>.  Repeat for each member and see if one of them alone causes the error. 2) Must be that the serialization logic of one of the classes uses a dictionary internally.

Comment: Does the problem only occur on one particular serialized set of data, or can you reproduce it by creating some new object, serializing it, then deserializing it?  If you can't re-create it that way, then maybe the serialized data is simply out of sync with the current version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it was not to do with the serialize of the objects but i was of course creating new objects then changing the structure from a dictionary to a list and then i had duplicate instances of the objects as i was declaring them incorrectly within some other code.

Sorry about the miss information!

Scott